# Ansible git module not checking out a branch

Tags: git, ansible

I'm using ansible to checkout my webapplication on EC2 web instances. My code is as followed:

```
- name: Checkout the source code
  git:
    accept_hostkey=yes
    depth=5
    dest={{ webapp_dir }}
    force=yes
    key_file=/var/tmp/webapp_deploy_key
    repo=git@github.com:MyRepo/web-app.git
    update=yes
    version={{ webapp_version }}
  register: git_output
```

As long as `webapp_version = master`it works perfectly. But as soon as I put a SHA1 or Branch name it will fail.

```
TASK: [webapp | Checkout the source code]
************************************* 
failed: [52.17.69.83] => {"failed": true}
msg: Failed to checkout some-branch
```

It's quite strange.

I use:

```
› ansible --version
ansible 1.9.1
  configured module search path = None
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

And again I will answer one of my own questions. The `depth=5` was the killer. Well don't use it if you want to have access to all your different versions ;)

Comment: For anyone else who lands here, I had to remove the `depth` property and then `rm -rf` my whole git directory before it would work.

Comment: Thanks @WindUpToy ! This did the job !

Comment: well, depth isn't really a problem unless you do want to checkout different branches there. in my case removing the src and running again was enough, with or without depth.

Answer (score 0):

It is the value of the webapp_version in your config file which might be a culprit. I used it in this fashion and tested the code it works for both master and release/1.0 values.

```
 - name: Checkout the source code
     git:
      dest=/tmp/dump
      force=yes
      key_file=ghtest
      repo=git@github.com:Myrepo/test.git
      update=yes
      version='release/1.0'
     register: git_output
```

Comment: I tried to do it explicit same as you before doesn't work either. I can see that there is no branch on the server beside master....

Answer (score -2):

This has nothing to do with git. Your YAML is wrong (I'm surprised it doesn't give you a parsing error). You should either write it like this:

```
- name: Checkout the source code
  git: >
    accept_hostkey=yes
    depth=5
    dest={{ webapp_dir }}
```

i.e. with a `>` after the `git:`, which tells YAML to concatenate the following lines into a single line, or like this:

```
- name: Checkout the source code
  git:
    accept_hostkey: yes
    depth: 5
    dest: "{{ webapp_dir }}"
```

i.e. using colons instead of equal signs. In this case the quotes around `{{ webapp_dir }}` are important (see [ansible's documentation about this issue](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#hey-wait-a-yaml-gotcha)).

Comment: I know about the quotes issue. Also the > is not needed as 100 tasks I wrote all work perfectly without the >. This checkout works so it's not a syntax error according to me. It only doesn't work when I specify a branch instead of master. But to entertain I tried you suggestion and it gave the same issue. So I can conclude it's not a syntax error.